# Unable to call Fragment's Method from Parent View

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, mobile

I am trying to call a Fragment's public Method from its Parent View and I followed [this](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDgOzCj8bJAhXE1I4KHdSOCw0QFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10903077%2Fcalling-a-fragment-method-from-a-parent-activity&usg=AFQjCNHQOqwYIeTUCTukPiRA6PHMn8GGhQ&sig2=OHtBT2vkoAttKCPAToJM7A), [this](https://www.google.lk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiDgOzCj8bJAhXE1I4KHdSOCw0QFgghMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F19334234%2Fcalling-fragment-method-from-activity&usg=AFQjCNE8eHaiUk52MUXzbYyD7ma2mHZPMQ&sig2=TXm8Om-RrLc_KKjdXjPplA) and these questions on Stack. However the method I need is not avilable when I try to call it from the Parent view.

Here's my code:

**Fragment:**

```
public class FirstTabView extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_tab_view, container, false);
            return rootView;
    }

     //The method I need to call
     public void PostStuff(String caption){
     }
}
```

**Parent View: (Which contains the Main View Pager)**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_view);

        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.mainpager);
        mAdapter = new HomePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

        //Getting the Fragment's Tag. o is the Pager's Fragment index. i.e.: The first fragment
        String fragment_tag = "android:switcher:" + pager.getId() + ":" + 0;
        FirstTabView fragment = (FirstTabView) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragment_tag);
        fragment.  <This is where I need to call the method and pass the parameter>   ();
        //The method however doesn't appear when I try to reference it
}
```

Am I calling the Fragment's method correctly from my Parent View? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

This is the adapter that I used to push the Fragments:

```
public class HomePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public HomePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
                case 0:
                    return new FirstTabView();
                case 1:
                    return new SecondTabView();
                case 2:
                    return new ThirdTabView();
                case 3:
                    return new FourthTabView();
                case 4:
                    return new FifthTabView();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // get item count - equal to number of tabs
            return 5;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception when you call the method ?

Comment: Sure thing. I edited it in @Ashwin

Comment: @Earthling your code is right. it should work

Comment: But the Fragment's method doesn't show up mate @MD Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @Earthling check [this](http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/tips/Android-call-fragment-method-from-activity.htm). may be help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save a reference of the FirstTabView to your MainActivity, then call the method of the fragment.

**FirstTabView**

```
public class FirstTabView extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_first_tab_view, container, false);
            return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //set this fragment to your MainActivity
        MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        mainActivity.setFirstTabView(this);
    }


     //The method I need to call
     public void PostStuff(String caption){

     }
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
private FirstTabView firstTabView;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ........
    if(firstTabView != null) {
        firstTabView.PostStuff("Hello World");
    }
}

public void setFirstTabView(FirstTabView firstTabView){
    this.firstTabView = firstTabView
}
```

Comment: Very clean code. Let me try this and get back to you now

Comment: Amazing! So simple and beautiful. Thank you, Shiba! You saved the day :)